# Encoding a sentence

Tags: c++, string, encryption

I am trying to encode a sentence in C++ and the only encryption I am getting back is the first letter of the word in the sentence instead of all of the letters in the sentence. This is my code below and the output I am getting is below my code. And below that is the output I SHOULD have.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
 int multi;
 int adder;
char words;

cout << "What is your multiplier?" << endl;
cin >> multi;

cout << "What is your adder?" << endl;
cin >> adder;

cout << "Enter in a sentence you want encrypted" << endl;
cin >> words;


cout << "Encrypted: " << endl;
cout << (int)words * multi + adder << endl;

return 0;}
```

my output:

What is your multiplier?

4

What is your adder?

3

Enter in a sentence you want encrypted

The butler did it

Encrypted:

339

This is the code I should have:

What is your multiplier?

4

What is your adder?

3

Enter in a sentence you want encrypted

The butler did it

Encrypted:

339 419 407 131 395 471 467 435 407 459 131 403 423 403 131 423 467

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you a beginner in C or C++ ? I think you should start from the basics on how to represent strings and use loops.

Comment: Encoding and encrypting are different things.

Answer (score 2):

In your code, `words` is a `char` variable, and can only store one character. Instead, you could declare `words` to be of type `std::string` and include the `string` library.

```
std::string words;
```

For calculating the value for each character, you would need to run a loop, such as

```
cout << "Encrypted: " << endl;
for(int i=0;i<words.size();i++)
{
    cout << (int)words[i] * multi + adder << " ";
}
cout << endl;
```

Comment: Beat me. only thing I'd do differently is use a range-based for. Have an up vote.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple issues:

1. `char words` ---- it will take just one character.
   Change it to `string words`
2. To have line with multiple words, use `getline` function

   ```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <string>
   using namespace std;

   int main ()
   {
       int multi;
       int adder;
       string words;

       cout << "What is your multiplier?" << endl;
       cin >> multi;
       cin.clear();

       cout << "What is your adder?" << endl;
       cin >> adder;

       cin.ignore();
       cout << "Enter in a sentence you want encrypted" << endl;
       getline(cin, words);


       cout << "Encrypted: " << endl;
       for(int i=0;i<words.length();i++)
       {
           cout << (int)words[i] * multi + adder << " ";
       }
       cout << endl;

       system("PAUSE");
       return 0;
   }
   ```

Comment: Multiple issues: (1) `using namespace std` is a terrible habit to get into. (2) `system("PAUSE")` is code that you should never use. (3) there is no such punctuation mark as `:-`. You can have *either* a colon or a dash. Not both jammed together. (4) to put a code block in a numbered list, you indent each line by an additional 4 spaces, for a total of 8 spaces. (I've fixed the latter two formatting problems, but otherwise left your code alone.)